# CMake can't get the value of VCTargetsPath when generating for UWP

Tags: c++, cmake, uwp, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to use CMake to build a Universal Windows App, but I get the following build error (latest Visual Studio 2019 and Windows 10 SDK are installed):

```
› cmake -B. -H<my source dir> -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.1+4616136f8 for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Build started 5/16/2020 9:52:00 PM.
    Project "C:\test\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(777,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'VCTargetsPath.vcxproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x64'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\test\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "C:\test\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "C:\test\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
    (_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform target) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(777,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'VCTargetsPath.vcxproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x64'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\test\CMakeFiles\3.17.2\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.07


  Exit code: 1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What does that mean? I've also tried to specify the exact Windows SDK version for `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION`, but no luck.

Comment: Please check if vcxproj file contains `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'"> 
   
    <OutputPath>xxxxx\</OutputPath>
   
</PropertyGroup>`

Comment: I also have the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. I did many things, therefore I cannot tell which one exactly solved the problem. But try the following.

From `VisualStudio Installer` app, click `Modify` and install `C++ Universal Windows Platform support for v142 build tools (ARM64)` individual component.

Comment: Thanks! While installing that package didn't change anything, I fixed it by installing the whole UWP dev workload.

Comment: I want to mention it is a huge mess while facing with the UWP. Let me point another question asked by me. In case you face it [SO question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906895/msbuild-flags-to-build-for-windowsstore-uwp/61917667#61917667)