# MSBuild flags to build for WindowsStore / UWP

Tags: msbuild, conan

Two days of research gave me no results. I want to configure a conanfile to build an existing `.sln` for UWP / WindowsStore, to make sure everything is allowed.

Here's an MSBuild part of the `conanfile.py`

```
class LibConan(ConanFile):
  def build(self)
    msbuild = MSBuild(self)
    msbuild.build(
      'library.sln',
      targets=['liblibrary'],
      platforms={'x86': 'Win32', 'x86_64': 'x64'},
      toolset=self.settings.compiler.toolset,
      use_env=False)
```

Where and what arguments/options should I put?

### NOTES

- The existing project doesn't provide `CMakeLists.txt`
- The `.sln` (library) is a third-party library, hence not applicable to change the `.sln` or `.vcxproj` files

Comment: You should pass 'WindowsStore' as settings.os: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/config_files/settings.yml.html

Comment: Is that enough?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/conan-io/conan/blob/918d198c586caa93d09ea869f70ac9a78e3d0ca3/conans/client/tools/win.py#L451

Comment: @uilianries Thanks, man. It means a lot to me. I spend so many hours trying to figure out this. Could you please make an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WindowsStore` is considered a `settings.os` in Conan. Thus, you need to configure your settings for such profile:

```
conan create . -s os=WindowsStore
```

Or, you can create a new [Conan profile](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/profiles.html) with such os.